# Position has been set, but z-index is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to create a step progress bar, but I have problems with CSS.
I want circles to be covered in lines，but it not work.
Demo is as follows: 
HTML:

```css
ol {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0.2em #e1e1e1 solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

li:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2em;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
</ol>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/scheinin/pen/MqzWQb)

Comment: if you only want to cover up the lines that are behind/in the circles, just add a background color to your :after

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a background to your circles:

```css
ol {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0.2em #e1e1e1 solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background:white;               /* add this */
}

li:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2em;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
  <li>
    Order received
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you just have to set `background-color` and not `color` on the &:after selector

```
&:after {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely

Answer (score 0):

add the background color to the

```
&:after {background:#fff;}
```

and your code will work fine.